# Scalar Variable error using var Table but not Temp Table

Tags: sql, variables, temp-tables

I am stumped with this one.  I have the following code it works fine up to the point of the last @POC_XLATE in the update statement and then I get the error MUST DECLARE SCALAR VARIABLE.
 If I change the table to a temp table the code works fine.  I have tried moving the select statement to the end of the code, that didn't work.  Hope someone has some suggestion on why it is doing this.  Thanks in advance.

```
declare  @POC_XLATE as TABLE(
    POC_XLATE_ID int  NULL,
    TAR_ID int NULL,
    POC_USERID varchar(50) NULL,
    ACTION_DATE datetime NULL
) 
insert into @POC_XLATE(POC_XLATE_ID, TAR_ID, POC_USERID, ACTION_DATE)
select * from POC_XLATE
where POC_XLATE.ACTION_DATE is null

select * from @POC_XLATE

update @POC_XLATE
set ACTION_DATE = TAR_DATA.OPEN_DATE
from TAR_DATA
where @POC_XLATE.TAR_ID = TAR_DATA.TAR_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

A column alias cannot start with a `@`.  That is the sign for a declared scalar variable.  So, use table aliases:

```
update p
    set ACTION_DATE = td.OPEN_DATE
    from  @POC_XLATE p JOIN
          TAR_DATA td 
          on p.TAR_ID = td.TAR_ID ;
```

But why you would write the query in two steps?

```
insert into @POC_XLATE(POC_XLATE_ID, TAR_ID, POC_USERID, ACTION_DATE)
    select p.POC_XLATE_ID, p.TAR_ID, p.POC_USERID, td.OPEN_DATE
    from POC_XLATE p left join
         TAR_DATA td 
         on p.TAR_ID = td.TAR_ID
    where p.ACTION_DATE is null;
```

One step is much cleaner than two.

Comment: Doing it this way to check that the right data is being transferred before I update the actual table..  The @POC_XLATE in the where part of the update statement is telling me I need to declare a scalar variable for the table which is already declared.  So why should I have to re-declare the table.

Comment: @tcmauldin . . . When SQL Server comes across a variable that starts with `@`, it assumes it is a *scalar* variable under most circumstances.  If a *scalar* variable does not exist, then execution fails.  The exception is in the `FROM` clause where table variables are allowed.